# Trouble running Chicken Scheme in Emacs

Tags: emacs, scheme, lisp, chicken-scheme

I recently got into Scheme through Racket and I now want to use Chicken Scheme. Emacs seems to be pretty much the only option I have for developping in Scheme other than Racket so I boot up Emacs which I am not very good at.

I had previously set up emacs for SBCL using [this](http://pchristensen.com/blog/articles/installing-sbcl-emacs-and-slime-on-windows-xp/) tutorial, but I am really not experienced with Emacs at all. (Note: I am on windows)

**What I did:**

- I set up a unix-like file structure like the tutorial above described, and I installed Chicken-Scheme in Z:\home\myname\bin\chicken-iup
- I tried following the instructions on [this page](http://wiki.call-cc.org/emacs) but there wasn't really much. It says I need quack but doesn't explain a lot, I just downloaded quack.el from the site and put it in my site-lisp folder
- I added the following lines to my .emacs folder

  (setq scheme-program-name "csi -:c")
  (require 'quack)
- On the page linked previously, there is this snapshot, which is what I want to get to

[image]

You can see at the top there is a file open to write text and the REPL at the bottom, however, when I open emacs and do M-x run-scheme, I can't get that

I have two choices, M-x run-scheme and then "chicken" gives me the Chicken intro screen but immediately says "process finished"

[image]

On the other hand, M-x run-scheme csi just gives me a blank buffer with seemingly no REPL

[image]

Running csi.exe directly in windows opens a console window with the intro text and the repl, but I want to have it in emacs like the first snapshot, which doesn't work

I've also tried chicken-slime SWANK backend but couldn't get it to work and searching google doesn't yield much help

So, does someone know what I need to do to be able to develop in Chicken Scheme in emacs

(Alternatively, if there are other Scheme environments for development outside of DrRacket I'd be interested to know, I haven't found much info apart from DrRacket or Emacs)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's odd that `M-x run-scheme` is prompting you for a Scheme interpreter.

Normally, `(setq scheme-program-name "csi -:c")` should define which Scheme program to use with `run-scheme`.  But perhaps Quack overrides `run-scheme`, which means it wouldn't use `scheme-program-name` (it's under "built-in support", and indeed the standard Scheme-mode will use this).  I'm not a fan of Quack, but you could try typing "csi -:c" instead of plain "csi". Like the manual says,

> The -:c is to force interactive mode, which is required on some platforms (most notably Windows).

Because Emacs can't fake a console on Windows like it can on *nix, CHICKEN thinks it's reading from a pipe on stdin, so it won't show you a prompt.

Like I said, I'm not a fan of Quack; AFAIK it doesn't add anything except "fancy lambda" and a large help menu (but I never use the menu in Emacs).  I'd rather start by just removing `(require 'quack)` from your `.emacs` (keeping the `(setq scheme-program-name)`), and restart Emacs, then type `M-x run-scheme` to see what happens.

Comment: Getting rid of (require 'quack) did indeed allow me to just do M-x run-scheme and get the Chicken scheme REPL. Thanks a lot